# JavaScript: supposed to execute functions sequentially, not actually doing so?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm seeing a lot of answers on StackOverflow that say that JavaScript executes code sequentially, but I can actually see my own JavaScript not doing so. From the following code:

```
function centre_map(lat, lng, zoom_level) {
    alert('centre_map');
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
    var latlng = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setCenter(latlng, zoom_level);
}        
function add_markers_within_bounds() {
    alert('add_markers_within_bounds'); 
    // add numerous BLUE markers within map bounds using MarkerClusterer
}
function add_marker(lat, lng, place_name, grid, county) {
    alert('add_marker');
    // add one ordinary RED Google Maps marker
}
centre_map('{{lat}}', '{{lng}}', 12);
add_markers_within_bounds('{{grid}}', '{{place_name}}');
add_marker('{{lat}}', '{{lng}}', '{{place_name}}', '{{grid}}', '{{county}}');
```

I get the following sequence of events:

1. 'centre_map' alert
2. 'add_markers_within_bounds' alert
3. 'add_marker' alert
4. individual RED marker appears on map (i.e. add_marker renders)
5. multiple BLUE markers appear on map (i.e. add_markers_within_bounds renders)

Why doesn't `add_markers_within_bounds` complete before `add_marker` gets under way: and how can I make it do so?

I know that one way might be to call `add_marker` from *within* `add_markers_within_bounds`, but for various reasons I'd rather keep it as a separate function.

Comment: Many Google Maps functions perform ajax calls with callbacks, so other Javascript will continue to execute (sequentially), until the asynchronous request completes.  Gotta dash out, so I don't have time to write a complete answer for you, sorry :-)

Comment: Also, you're using the Maps API v2 - you might want to migrate to v3. It won't fix your issue, but it's probably a good idea to not use a deprecated system. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Comment: You're both absolutely right. Thanks - I've upgraded to v3. Handily that solves the problem by allowing you to set display priority on markers, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API sometimes involves sending a request to Google to get the data. If one of these actions involves requesting data, it will be delayed until the HTTP request is complete, and the rest of the code will continue on without it.

It seems to me that `add_marker` probably does not involve requesting data, since you already provide the coordinates, whereas `add_markers_within_bounds` may involve downloading data to know what the coordinates actually are. As such, `add_marker` will always happen first, while the data for the other markers is still busy downloading.

I'm not sure how the Google Maps API works, but you may be able to specify `add_marker` as a callback to occur once all the data for `add_markers_within_bounds` is ready.

Comment: event delegation can also be used, there are some plugins available for js event delefation

Comment: You're of course right, deleted my own answer - didn't think that one through ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the operations on `GMap2` are asynchronous (likely with **A** JAX)? If so, you may need to put a block operation after the call if you want to be sure of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want that function to be called after the execution of the former. this might help you but i m not 100% sure as i couldnt test it for a scenario similar to yours.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
        add_marker();
    }, 0);
```

giving 0 as set timeout's time forces it to execute it at the end